# How to access sub-pages of a man page

Tags: perl, manpages

If I type

```
man perl
```

on the command line, I get the man page for perl, which lists all of the sections into which the perl man pages have been split. How do I access one of these sections? For instance, the first section is perlintro, but if I type

```
man perlintro
```

I get an error saying there is no such manual entry. How do I access these parts of the manual?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means that some of those `man` pages are missing. You should re-install the package that contains them. Since you didn't say what OS or distribution, I can't give any further guidance.

```
man perlinfo
```

works for me.

**Edit:**

Try:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install perl-doc
```

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Ah hah! It turns out I didn't have perl docs installed. apt-get install perl-doc fixed it.